# $\sum \frac{1}{(n(x+\pi))^2}, \;x\in(-\pi,\pi)$, does not converge uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the series,

$$\sum \frac{1}{(n(x+\pi))^2}, \;x\in(-\pi,\pi)$$

I want to examine whether the series converge uniformly or not.

Efforts:

Let's assume on the contrary that convergence is uniform, then $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{(n(x+\pi))^2}\to 0$ uniformly

Now take $a_n=-\pi+{1\over n}$

$f_n(a_n)=\frac{1}{(n(-\pi +{1\over n}+\pi))^2}$

So $f_n(a_n)\to 1$, Therefore we conclude that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to zero.

Hence our assumption was incorrect and the originial series is not uniformlly convergent.

Thanks for reading. Is this a right way to solve?

Comment: Yes, this is the best way to answer the question.